# jquery error for Editor

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

`enter code here`I am having the following code in my view

```
@Html.EditrFor(m=>m.Date1)
@Html.EditrFor(m=>m.Date2)
```

In my jquery I am having

```
  var test = $("#Date1").Val();
              var test1 = $("#Date2").Val();
```

But it`s giving me errors and it`s not able top read the Date1 and Date2 Values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using captial **V**.

replace `Val` with `val`